# How to round currency (decimals) to Millions? (C#)

Tags: c#

I have decimal currency amounts (from SQl2k* tables as 32,8) and I would like to round them to Millions with 2 decimal places.

The system will be displaying 1000s of rows with multiple amounts in them, and I need to summarise the totals for various categories into a "quick view".

e.g.

```
123,456,789.12345678
goes to
123.46

6,655,443,332.2110099
goes to
6,655.44
```

etc

I know there are issues with rounding and decimal/floating point math:

```
45,454,454.454545
goes to
45.46 OR 45.45 ?
```

so also any advice on what's best to use would also be very much appreciated.

---

Two more examples (of what I'd EXPECT...not what might actually be mathematically correct!)

```
555444444.444444 => 555.44
555444444.444445 => 555.45
```

I would expect the final "5" of the second example to cascade up to the decimal place?

Comment: WHy not simply devide by 1000?

Comment: not sure what you want to achieve if you round them won't those change the final Totals ?

Comment: From your examples you are not rounding to millions (whatever that means), but dividing by 1000, and then rounding to two decimal places.

Comment: @V4Vendetta: The totals will be still in full decimal places, just the display I need in millions only.

Comment: @sternr: I would love to...but there is a difference - e.g. 129,009,999 => 129.00 vs 129.01 means 10,000.  I may need to round to Billions as well...in which case, my managers may well notice the odd million missing...and my new ferrari ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
decimal d = Math.Round(inValue/1000000m, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 double v = Math.Round(45454454.454545, 2);
```

Will return `45454454.45`

So solution would be:

```
 double factor = 1000000;
 double v1 = Math.Round(123456789.12345678 / factor, 2); //// 123.46  
 double v2 = Math.Round(6655443332.2110099 / factor, 2); //// to 6,655.44
```

Comment: @BlueChippy : just finished and tested my snipped

Comment: Hmm..I thought that worked...then tried 555444444.444444 and 555444444.444445.  I would have expected that trailing 5 on the second number to "cascade" up and make the total 555.45, but both come back as 555.44.  I trie both ToEven and AwayFromZero?

Comment: @BlueChippy - Why would you expect X.44444445 to round up to X.45? What do you expect X.4449 to round to?

Comment: @BlueChippy Your assumptions are wrong, trailing 5 mustn't and, as expected, doesn't "cascade".

Comment: @Petr Abdulin:  Thanks Petr...but any idea why not?

Comment: @AAT: My expectation (based upon nothing but gut feeling!) was that anything that would be "removed" by the rounding would be rounded up first, and in revers order. So X.4449 would round to X.45: The 9 rounds up first making X.445, the 5 rounds up making X.45 - and we stop there because thats our decimal precision.

Comment: @BlueChippy why not -- the mathematical rules, as a general answer. The simple and intuitive would be that in X.4449, the 0.0449 part is less than 0.0500 so why it should be rounded up? note the difference that 0.0009 is greater then 0.0005 so it's ronded up.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO You should use [Bankers Rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bankers_rounding) instead of Your 'cascade' rounding